# Is probability mass function (PMF) the "law of X"?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Are they two the same?
If not, what's the differences between these two?

In continuous case, is PMF also equal to the integration of probability density function?

Answer (score 0):

For a discrete random variable, $X$, the probability mass function, denoted $f_X$ satisfies the following $$\mathbb{P}[X\in\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_X(a_n).$$

---

For a continuous random variable, $Y$, the analogue to PMF is called the probability *density* function, denoted $f_Y$. And it satisfies for any measurable set $U$, $$\mathbb{P}[Y\in U]=\int_U f_Y(y)\mathrm{d}y.$$

---

The *law* of a random variable, $Z$ (discrete, continuous or neither), is a probability *measure*. And if we denote it by $\mathcal{L}_Z$, we for any measurable set $V$ $$\mathcal{L}_Z(V)=\mathbb{P}[Z\in V].$$

Comment: "event U / event V" No, U and V are measurable subsets of the target set while events are measurable subsets of the source set Omega.

Comment: Indeed - corrected.